# Am I creating SQL table correctly?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database table for an android app using SQLite and I'm having issues. The app would crash every time I try to dump the database. It gives me an error "no such column: _id". I double checked multiple times to make sure there's a column for _id, but it's still crashing. Am I creating the table correctly?

```
public static final String NAME = "contacts";
public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
public static final String COL_INFO = "info";
public static final String COL_SCORE = "score";

final private static String CREATE_CMD = 
    "CREATE TABLE " + NAME + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + COL_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + COL_INFO + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + COL_SCORE + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
```

Comment: The SQL is right, the error is really misleading you from a problem in other part of your code.

Comment: maybe you should try posing the stacktrace.. so we aren't wasting our time guessing what could be going wrong... learn the VERY basics of debugging.

Comment: @MikeW : At what point is a leading underscore illegal as a field name in a SQLite database?

Comment: @MikeW In many cases, the Android API *requires* the name `_id`.

Comment: If you added the column to your SQLite helper `onCreate()` afterwards, you'll need to ensure `onCreate()` is called again. Either 1) wipe application data (using settings -> apps -> app info), or 2) bump up the database version number you pass to `SQLiteOpenHelper` super constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its correct, maybe you are calling incorrect table column.

Post the segment of code where you try call the table.

Comment: This is not an answer; it should have been a comment.